# Is whatsapp/Facebook messenger password encrypted in the device?

Tags: encryption, chat, ejabberd, whatsapp

I am trying to figure out how to handle the credentials for reconnection process for a chatserver from a mobile device, i know the credentials probably has to be stored in the device.

I am wondering if the password is encrypted before they are stored? But as whatsapp and these chat do not require a password on open,so i am assuming they don't or they use a unique value per device to store them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both iOS and Android offer file encryption features for developer to encrypt / protect sensitive data. It is typically used to store local password.

You should make sure on Android that your are using the proper file storage mode: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html

and you should look for Keychain on iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html

Comment: Hi, thanks! Yer i am using Keychain and Android Keystore for the process. Maybe i am confusing myself....well i think i am, but i am just not sure how does the encryption process protects the credentials. For example, if another person knows the key to call for the credentials, then they can just pull my password??

Comment: No, only your own application car read it, that's the purpose.